# Check constraint to ensure unique id created

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a check constraint for a RaceId that will ensure that the id contains 2 letters (the first two letters of the country a race is in) and then the next available number seeded from 1000

Comment: Um, what is your question please? What is your current solution? :)

Comment: You can use unique index to ensure uniqueness, and check constraint to check the country. Checking that the id is the "next" is slightly dangerous, because then you can't delete any rows.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can't achieve checking the "next available number from 1000". Check constraints can not access to anything else than the value of the field  to check itself.

I guess you rather wish to add an insert trigger, which sets value of RaceId from the country code plus a unique number *at the time when the row is inserted* automatically and correctly.

---

You might wish to consider this from the perspecitve of the data model, if you stick to using constraints only. You have two pieces of data - the country, and the race number - stored in one field. Instead, have a separate country field, and use foreign keys to a separate country table to ensure that no invalid country symbols can be entered. Then have a unique constraint on the race id number to make it unique, and a check constraint to ensure that it is always bigger than 1000. (This raceid column can be an autoincrement column too, this way it gets its next value automatically.)

When querying the data, simply concatenate the country symbol and the race id to one field in your select.